# CDN with Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I create the the Storage account, CDN Profile and CDN endpoint from powershell. But adding images to the storage account is a manual process after creating all azure components. Now we have the issue that images are not showing up in page. When I try to access the CDN image url directly, I get this error

`The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server`

But I can access the content directly by using blob storage url to ensure content exist. I tried changing the `caching rules` , but nothing is working. I have `standard verizon` cdn profile.

Any suggestions?

**Update1 :** When I delete the endpoint and recreate the endpoint with all images already loaded in Storage account, everything works fine. Any idea what is the predictable behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you're using a "/" with the root container where the blob is present (sub-folders). for now the "/" are not supported, you can get around it by referencing the root container in the link, ex:

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/myphoto
```

When using the CDN, the format should look like the following:

```
http://<EndpointName>.azureedge.net/<myPublicContainer>/<BlobName>
```

There is also a cool tutorial on how to host static sites via blobs and CDN worth checking out: https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn

**Documentation:**
You can get more info from these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Working-with-the-Root-Container?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn